# DataVirt Error "MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host Start Exception in service jboss.web.development.default-host./"

Tags: java, jboss, data-virtualization, redhat-datavirt

I am trying to deploy JBoss DataVirt on a Linux site.  The **standalone.sh** script works until it gets to the **"$JAVA" JVM_OPTVERSION** command after the moves of the logs to backup files.  I get the error:

```
MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host
Start Exception in service jboss.web.development.default-host./
```

Does anyone have any idea why I am getting this error?  It has kept me from deploying and running DataVirt, and there seems to be no way to get past it.

Comment: Did you run through the provided installer to install this?

Comment: I might not have.  I will "redo from start" with what I am certain is the correct installer.

Comment: I reinstalled DataVirt under another home directory having much more disk space, and it works just fine now.  Thank you for your help.